# Spark "Task not serializable" when using field variables

Tags: scala, apache-spark, serialization

My testing code is pretty simple and it's pretty much copied from the spark example, however,

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession

import scala.util.Properties

class MyTest(sparkSession: SparkSession, properties: java.util.Properties) {

  val spark: SparkSession = sparkSession

  val sparkHome = Properties.envOrElse("SPARK_HOME", "/spark")
  val props = properties

  def run(): Unit = {
    val logFile = sparkHome + "/README.md"
    val logData = spark.read.textFile(logFile).cache()
    val numAs = logData.filter(line => line.contains(props.get("v1"))).count()
    val numBs = logData.filter(line => line.contains(props.get("v2"))).count()
    println(s"Lines with a: $numAs, Lines with b: $numBs")

  }
}
```

However, when I try to run it, it always reports `Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.SparkException: Task not serializable` and points to line `val numAs = logData.filter(line => line.contains(props.get("v1"))).count()`

Well, after I change it to

```
val v1 = props.get("v1")
val v2 = props.get("v2")

val numAs = logData.filter(line => line.contains(v1)).count()
val numBs = logData.filter(line => line.contains(v2)).count()
```

The exception is gone.  I think the reason is spark complains about `props` can't be serialized.  However, java.util.Properties actually implements java.io.Serializable

```
class Properties extends Hashtable<Object,Object> {
```

and Hashtable

```
public class Hashtable<K,V>
    extends Dictionary<K,V>
    implements Map<K,V>, Cloneable, java.io.Serializable {
```

Why do I still gets this exception?

The reason I need to do this is because my spark job has some command line parameters, and need to pass them into my spark job class instance.  Any best practice for me to do this?

Comment: try broadcasting props and use it inside filter function

Comment: Could you elaborate?

Comment: instead of doing `val props = properties` try doing `val props = spark.sparkContext.broadcast(properties).value` and let me know if it works. I shall answer it as an answer

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This line

```
line => line.contains(props.get("v1"))
```

implicitly captures `this`, which is `MyTest`, since it is the same as:

```
line => line.contains(this.props.get("v1"))
```

and `MyTest` is not serializable.

Define `val props = properties` inside `run()` method, not in class body.